# How to restrict or hide users to specific drives only (not typical drives combinations)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, hard-drive, restrictions, hidden

How can I restrict users (not admins) to access to specific drives?

I know there is gp that allows to restrict typical combinations of drives, like C, A, B, D etc... But I would like to allow all drives, except P:

I readed and old method but I would like to be sure that it works with 2012 version.

Thank you all,

Comment: The Group Policy management tools only have minimal built-in documentation, but they do usually say when a policy only applies to certain versions of Windows.  You should also note that the policy restricting access to drives isn't a security feature, i.e., a determined user may be able to bypass the restrictions.

Comment: `I readed and old method but I would like to be sure that it works with 2012 version` - Were you going to share that with us or do we have to guess?

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks, could you help me to prevent accessing to P: drive if gpo is not good?

Comment: @joeqwerty sorry, this is superuser thread, but for Windows 7 https://superuser.com/questions/238235/how-to-hide-drive-for-specific-users-in-windows-7

Comment: If you need to reliably prevent the users from accessing the P: drive, set the security permissions for the files and folders on the drive accordingly.  Or perhaps use `diskpart` to mark the volume as hidden so that it doesn't get given a drive letter at all, depending on your scenario.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thank you, but this P: drive is like virtual. It is created automatically with pCloud app (like dropbox) and I can't disable it and I can't add permissions folders or using diskpart. This is why I pretend to use gpo or something like this... Any ideas? thanks in advance